# HTML template does on exist (base.html), Pycharm interpreter is unable to import views from my app name = 'app'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

enter image description here
[image]

i am unable to import views for my app in urls.py

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to import app.views when you already did `path('', include(app.urls))`

Go to app/urls.py and import the view there
`from . import views`